Approximating the Gaussian White Noise stochastic process for numerical applications
The problem I have at hand is a rather amateurish one. For a modeling task, I have worked out the stochastic differential equation the random process of interest should obey, and the gaussian white noise process $\xi(t)$ makes an appearance. For example:
$$
\frac{dx}{dt} = -\beta x + \alpha x \xi(t)
$$
You might observe that this is just the SDE $dx=-\beta x dt+\alpha x dW$ with W a Wiener process, which has a closed form solution - the problem I actually have is a bit more complicated and does not admit a closed form solution.
My goal would be to sample paths of $\xi(t)$ in discrete steps ($\xi(0)$, $\xi(\Delta t)$, $\xi(2 \Delta t)$ etc.) to be used in a numerical scheme, if $\xi(s)$ was not a gaussian RV with infinite variance. So I want to replace $\xi(t)$ with another stochastic process $\xi^*(t)$ that was actually tractable and bound the error I'd get from such approximation but I am not sure how to go on about this. Any pointers towards resources or comments on the feasibility of such a scheme would be greatly appreciated.

There are stochastic methods for SDE, like Euler-Maruyama as the most simple one. There are other schemes that increase the weak or strong order by some half-integers, but mainly increase the stability of the integration. Using white noise is ambiguous, the main interpretation of the stochastic term go via the Ito or Stratanovich integral, giving different results.

Not sure if it is relevant, but John Hull's "Options, Futures and Other Derivates" discusses in Chapter 20 Basic Numerical Procedures, when analytic results like the Black-Scholes formula do not exist. Maybe you can draw inspiration from this.
